# Which SKLearn interface defines .fit, .predict etc

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Examining the [`sklearn.base`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.base), more specifically `BaseEstimator`, and the different mixins, it is obvious that some of the mixins are dependent on the the ability to call `.fit` or `.predict`.

For example, if we'd look at the [`RegressorMixin`](http://%20https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb/sklearn/base.py#L408) we'd see it relies on the `.predict` method.

My question is why is there no implementation of an interface / abstract class that enforces the implementation of these methods?

I'd expect to have something like `BaseRegressor` that has `.predict()` as an abstract method and `BaseClassifier` to have `.predict_proba()` and `.predict()` - or something similar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few things which together make it probably more clear why things are done in a package like `scikit-learn`, the way they are:

- duck typing vs inheritance: you can find very long arguments about which one is a better approach, and while they both have their advantages and disadvantages, at the end of the day, it comes down to what people in a community are used to. As somebody who does a lot of Python these days, I love duck typing, and I'm very comfortable with it. At the same time, 15 years ago, I loved abstract classes and OOP and what not, and I wouldn't understand why you would do things any other way. What I'm trying to say, is that people in Python like duck typing and that's partly why you see the pattern very often in some of its core packages.
- duck typing, contrib packages and extentions: sometimes checking an input, we can either check its type, or duck type it for a certain functionality. If we check the type, that means any input to that method should actually inherit from those classes, whereas if you duck type them, they can simply be implementing those methods and they're fine. This is important because if a developer is writing an estimator outside `scikit-learn`, for instance, which they want to be compatible with certain parts of `scikit-learn`, they don't have to depend on `scikit-learn` as a dependency (because that's how they can then inherit a certain class from the package), and simply implement those methods. If developers have the constraints to keep their package and their dependencies lightweight, this becomes relevant (and we have seen these exact issues in `scikit-learn`).
- `Mixin` classes: the idea behind the `Mixin` classes is not really that the child classes should inherit them and implement their methods; but it's more about adding a functionality to existing classes through them without having to copy/paste or reimplement any method. For instance, the [`TransformerMixin`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/801cca8e73215d4946f05379319d97156be659d6/sklearn/base.py#L528) adds the `fit_transform` method to an object, assuming it already has `fit` and `transform`, without caring about weather the object is an estimator or a transformer. Again, you could argue that a certain design pattern from OOP may be *better* here, but that's a never ending argument, and this approach works, and the developers are comfortable with it.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, I tried Googling it and couldn't find material about the arguments for/against duck typing / abstract inheritance, would you recommend any resource?

Comment: I just googled "duck typing vs inheritance" and it does show quite a few useful links :)

Answer (score 2):

The common idiom in python is 'duck typing' - if it behaves like a duck it's a duck, if it implements `fit` or any other relevant function it's a model for sklearn

there's also the concept of abstract base classes, but it's usage is less common

see more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Comment: I know what duck typing is, I don't get what is the advantage of working that way, when you already implement inheritance and mixins? Why take the approach of duck typing in a static structure like this?

Comment: Why shouldn't `BaseEstimator` oblige you to implement `fit` and `predict` (or other base class for that matter)? Why take the duck tape approach when you already implement the inheritance?

Comment: the mixin classes are used for implementation inheritance, and they aren't suitable for all cases.
so even if an interface approach was used, they would probably supply a separate pure interface.

Comment: exactly, why isn't there one? I can only see (in this case) disadvantages of using duck typing, while providing an abstract class seems to have only advantages... Now its up to you to "guess" you need to implement `fit`, `predict`, `predict_proba` etc